# Angular 2 revert to previously active md-tab when pressing back

Tags: javascript, angular

I have md-tab-group of tabs that route to different components:

```
<div class="course-menu-container">
    <md-tab-group (selectChange)="onLinkClick($event)"
              [selectedIndex]="selectedTab">
       <md-tab label="Announcements"></md-tab>
       <md-tab label="Assignments"></md-tab>
    </md-tab-group>
</div>
<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Which is controlled by the component with this function:

```
onLinkClick(e : any) {
    switch (e.index) {
    case 0:
       this.router.navigate(['announcements'], { relativeTo: this.thisRoute });
       break;
    case 1:
       this.router.navigate(['assignments'], { relativeTo: this.thisRoute });
       break;
    default:
       break;
 }
}
```

The issue is that when I use the click on different tabs and press back in the browser, the previous component loads but the selected tab is still the last one clicked. Example, first I press "Announcements", then "Assignments", after I press back and the browser is back at "Announcements" but the selected tab is still "Assignments".

Comment: You'll need to listen to router event and change the selected tab programmatically.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: First by searching 'angular router event' and 'change md-tab selection programmatically' on SO I suppose? I reckon there are tons of answers on both topics.

Comment: this is not the correct approach, instead, make the selected tab a route parameter and subscribe to the route params in the host component and link the active tab to that route param.